# $\partial(M \times N) = (\partial{M} \times \bar{N})\cup (\bar{M}\times\partial{N})$

Tags: general-topology

Let $M \subset X$ and $N \subset Y$, then how can I prove that $\partial(M \times N) = (\partial{M} \times \bar{N})\cup (\bar{M}\times\partial{N})$.

Any help with a nice solution will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The boundary $\partial A$ of a set its closure $\bar A$ minus its interior $\mathrm{int} A$. As the the interior and the closure are disjoint you can also write this as $\bar A=\partial A \uplus \mathrm{int} A$. Now work out what the closure and the interior of $M\times N$ are. Then split the result for the closure up in disjoint parts and subtract the interior. What's left over should the result that your looking for.

Another way you might go: if a point $x$ is on the boundary of $A$, then every  open set containing $x$, i.e. every neighbourhood of $x$, intersects $A$ *and* its complement $\complement A$. Now you need to show two directions: (a) if all neighbourhoods of $x$ intersect $M\times N$ and $\complement(M\times N)=(X\times Y)-(M\times N)$ then $x$ is in $\partial M\times \bar N$ or in $\bar M\times\partial N$ (non-exclusive). (b) The other way round: if $x$ is in one of those sets on the right, show that each of its neighbourhoods intersects $M\times N$ and $\complement(M\times N)$.